# MongoDB Aggregate with mergeObjects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a statistics collection that contains the statistics for every day, so every day I have a different document, currently the only valid statistic that I have is "accuracy".

Accuracy is a `Record<string, number>` an `object` `{ [string]: number }` basically, the keys are dynamic so I don't know beforehand what keys are going to be, but for this instance, there are valid keys: `low`, `medium`, `high`.

```
db.getCollection('statistics').aggregate( [
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            accuracy: { $push: "$accuracy" }
        }
    },
] )
```

Which results in:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "accuracy" : [ 
        {
            "low" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "low" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

But I don't want them to be both in different indexes, I want them to be accumulated and added together as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "accuracy" : {
        "low" : 10
    }
}
```

So that led me to find this:

```
db.getCollection('statistics').aggregate( [
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            accuracy: { $mergeObjects: "$accuracy" }
        }
    },
] )
```

The `$mergeObjects`, but with that another issue arises, it just merges and overrides the values and the output is wrong:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "accuracy" : {
        "low" : 6
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea how to increment that count that would be much appreciated, `$mergeObjects` plus some sort of accumulation `$add` would be ideal but I couldn't find any useful resource in the docs for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$set` - Convert the key-value pair from the `accuracy` field to an array of objects consisting of `k` and `v` fields.
2. `$unwind` - Descontruct the `accuracy` array into multiple documents.
3. `$group` - Group by `accuracy.k` and perform sum with `accuracy.v`.
4. `$group` - Group all documents, construct an array of objects consisting of `k` and `v` fields, convert the array into a key-value pair, and add into the `accuracy` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      accuracy: {
        $objectToArray: "$accuracy"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$accuracy"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$accuracy.k",
      value: {
        $sum: "$accuracy.v"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      accuracy: {
        $push: {
          $arrayToObject: [
            [
              {
                k: "$_id",
                v: "$value"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QEWmLUA_cwh)

Comment: Thanks that does seem to solve once of the issues of accumalation for the specific field but I still would like to know if I could replace that "0" with the accumalted fields.

Comment: Hi, *I could replace that "0" with the accumalted fields*, what do you mean 0, value? Would be great if you can create a demo in Mongo Playground.

Comment: Ah looks like I solved it... thank you for the help everyone! Solution here, https://mongoplayground.net/p/-39F0XRoIyF